# Nyquist theory for sampling data from TMP36

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, sensor, power-engineering, frequency-measurement

Is there any way to make sure that sampling temperature(voltage) using arduiono UNO  from TMP36 sensor does not violate Nyquist theory?

Answer (score 1):

No matter how hard you try there will be high frequency noise on the signal that will violate nyquist theory and will alias down into the baseband. The question is how much noise do you get and how much filtering do you need to do to make it acceptable.

For the signal itself, if you go to extreme applications where the bandwidth for a special temperature sensor (that I was involved with) had to exceed 50 kHz then you have no option but to sample at above 100 kHz. We chose 200 kHz sampling on this occasion to make the design of the reconstruction filters much easier.

In most cases a few tens of Hz is fine so, make sure you sample at least 2.5 times higher than your wanted baseband signal and use as good an anti-alias filter as you can afford or justify. The faster the sampling rate above baseband the easier it is to design an anti-alias filter but, don't forget noise if you really want accuracy down to below 0.3 deg C.

Answer (score 0):

In the data sheets there are several graphs showing temperature response.  The worst of these is the stirred oil bath.  A rule of thumb is that the bandwidth of the signal can be approximated using this formula;

Bandwidth = 0.35/risetime

The oil bath rise time is about 3 seconds.  This says the maximum frequency of the temperature signal will be about 0.12Hz.  You need to sample higher than 0.24Hz to completely reconstruct the temperature signal.  Of course this implies an impossible to construct low pass filter so you need to go higher.

If you are measuring something where the response time is less than the oil bath, the response will be slower and the bandwidth will be lower.

Here is the graph from the data sheet showing the response time in and oil bath;
[image: TPM 36 response time].

You can estimate the frequency of the TPM36 from this.  If the oil was at 0C for a long time and you instantly moved it into oil at 100C this graph shows how long it would take for the TPM36 to change from 0 to 100.  The rise time is taken from 10% to 90%.  So the time it would take for the TPM36 say 10C until it said 90C would be about 3 seconds.  The formula I gave converts this to the highest frequency in the signal.  It would be about 0.12Hz.  Nyquist says you have to sampling at 0.24Hz.  This means you are sampling about 40,000 times faster than needed.

Comment: Thanks...i am newbie so difficult for me to get the concepts..The clock of ADC in Arduino UNO, 16 MHz clock with the prescaler 128, making clock input into ADC = 125 kHz & it takes 13 cycles for ADC to make a complete anal. to dig. conversion, the sampling rate is approx. 9.6 kHz. From Nyquist theorem, the maxm signal frequency that can be captured is 4.8 kHz. The maxm frequency in our signal coming from TMP36 sensor <= 4.8 kHz.Is there any way that I can check theoretical frequency range from TMP36 in datasheet or is it should be done experimentally?

Answer (score 0):

For any desired SNR thus accuracy, the noise above nyquest rate must be filtered before input by at least your desired SNR.

This is easily accomplished by Integrate and Dump ADC and not by SAR type ADC's where aliasing errors are dominated by noise above 1/2 sampling rate.

If you don't have an IDC type converter , then estimate the signal BW by environmental slew rate = V/s= 0.35/f and determine noise level attenuation needed from input spectrum and design the order and slope of filter to satisfy both band pass/reject specs to meet desired SNR or 1/%error.

you may also review digital IDC methods https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/integrateanddump.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop

BTW where is your analysis of the signal noise??

Comment: Thanks Tony..Here is what I got for sensor noise..10 mV voltage change corresponds to change of temperature by 1℃ .
RMS value (ac coupling mode) of the sensor signal measured through Tektronix Oscilloscope 2002C gives the average sensor noise. Measured value = Sensor noise (σ_s)= 5.97 mV = 0.597℃ ≈ 0.60℃. TMP36 is isolated and connected to the oscilloscope to measure that value

Comment: @Dinesh  can't you see the frequencies of the noise and estimate what they are in terms of range of f and amplitude?  details details. Noise is defined in spec as uV/root(BW[Hz])

Comment: Thanks Tony..the frequency of noise is 2.78MHz from the snapshot of Oscilloscope screenI posted in yesterday's post , I also looked at the voltage noise density vs frequency curve of TMP36, but could not figure it out what it is explaining. Does not rms value (in ac coupling mode) give the enough informaton about the sensor(isolated) noise? I m sorry, I just started learning..I coud not estimate range of f and amplitude also...I would be very grateful for your help

Comment: try to change frequency with capacitance and see it is a resonant circuit due to bad layout. this is NOT due to the sensor but other factors related to interference or supply noise.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure if you are sampling your signal fast enough (to comply with Nyquist-Shannon-Kotelnikov sampling theorem) you just take measurements with several different increasing sampling rates, and compare resulting time plots. If the next higher sampling frequency gives you the same result, it is good enough. Of course, this method requires  to apply the same or very similar signal. Keep in mind that the transfer function of the system is not only by sensor itself, but by entire assembly of the sensor and the thermal mass of the object to which it is attached. So if you have a massive tank of something, the changes in temperature can be pretty slow, and the sampling can be correspondingly slow.

Answer (score 0):

Chunks of material, of differing sizes, have different thermal timeconstants.

Silicon, 1meter cube, has 11,400 seconds timeconstant
Silicon, 0.1meter cube (10cm cube), has 114 seconds timeconstant: yes, 100X faster.
Silicon, 0.01meter cube (1cm cube), has 1.14 seconds timeconstant: yes, 10,000x faster.
Silicon, 1mm cube, has 11.4 milliseconds timeconstant; yes, 1MillionX faster.

I use silicon/sand as approximation for many thermal issues, such as the response of resistors formed of metal films deposited on ceramic substrates.